# Import Dividend Data in Google Sheets - XML

Tags: xml, google-sheets, import, stock

I built my own portfolio tracker in Google sheets.
For ETFs, I would like to import the dividend data from justetf.com with IMPORTXML.
I can reach a lot of the elements on the pages, but I'm unable to retrieve the data from the dividend table under "Monthly dividends in EUR".

[image: Monthly dividends in EUR]

By copying the xml from Chrome, I have tried things like:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.justetf.com/en/etf-profile.html?query=IE00BDVJF675&groupField=index&from=search&isin=IE00BDVJF675#returns","/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[10]/div/div[5]/div[3]")
```

Can you help me with the XML syntax I should use to access the table cells?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=IMPORTHTML(https://www.justetf.com/en/etf-profile.html?query=IE00BDVJF675&groupField=index&from=search&isin=IE00BDVJF675#dividends", "table", 12)
```

[image]

---

### update:

getting monthly dividends is not possible because any of the google sheets import formulae do not support the scrapping of JavaScript elements. you can always test this by disabling JS for a given site and usually, only what's left can be scrapped

[image]

Comment: Hi Player, indeed this works well and gives the dividends per year. What I was trying to accomplish was to read out the table of dividends per month, as illustrated with the link in the original question. Would you also know hoe to read out that table? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JanWestra answer updated

Comment: Thanks a lot Player. This makes sense. Really appreciate your help!